# When I submit my app IOS returns crash error on Itunesconnect. Ionic3

Tags: xcode, ionic3, testflight

I'm trying to publish my app IOS in testflight, but return this error, how do I fix this?

I made build using ios cordova build ios, in xcode some warnings of images appeared, but I was able to generate the version and send it to the Itunesconnect, but always return is rejected.

I have no experience with IOS apps this is my first publish im IOS platform, my app works fine in Android / Google Play.

```
{"app_name":"appName","timestamp":"2019-02-27 06:03:27.54 +0800","app_version":"1.0.1","slice_uuid":"a9dacbda-c630-3176-97a3-ca04bd1548f7","adam_id":1438755380,"build_version":"1.0.1","bundleID":"br.com.appName","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.1.4 (16D57)","incident_id":"92E39825-2881-4003-80AB-9796EEAD112E","name":"appName"}
Incident Identifier: 92E39825-2881-4003-80AB-9796EEAD112E
CrashReporter Key:   9b4ce711a76e3812347dc72bdfba6c4be8bd4c4c
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             appName [5935]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/49D49234-B636-4ED5-82B8-C77169E0BAAF/appName.app/appName
Identifier:          br.com.appName
Version:             1.0.1 (1.0.1)
AppStoreTools:       10B63
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           br.com.appName [2926]


Date/Time:           2019-02-27 06:03:27.1874 +0800
Launch Time:         2019-02-27 06:03:26.8833 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1.4 (16D57)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1f4b71ea4 0x1f3d41a50 0x1f4a8b78c 0x1f551e29c 0x2216fb6d8 0x1f4a5b558 0x2216f8348 0x2216f8d0c 0x221a50208 0x221a50858 0x221a4ed68 0x2212ea93c 0x2212f35bc 0x2212ea5b8 0x2212eaf58 0x2212e9058 0x2212e8d04 0x2212edec4 0x2212eee24 0x2212edd7c 0x2212f2c68 0x221a4d34c 0x221638244 0x1f75a89d4 0x1f75b379c 0x1f75b2e94 0x1f45aa484 0x1f454de10 0x1f75e7a9c 0x1f75e7728 0x1f75e7d44 0x1f4b020e0 0x1f4b02060 0x1f4b01944 0x1f4afc810 0x1f4afc0e0 0x1f6d75584 0x221a50c00 0x100fd62d0 0x1f45babb4)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001f4707104 0x1f46e4000 + 143620
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f4783020 0x1f4781000 + 8224
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001f465ed78 0x1f4607000 + 359800
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f3d28f78 0x1f3d27000 + 8056
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f3d29120 0x1f3d27000 + 8480
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001f3d41e58 0x1f3d3b000 + 28248
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f3d350fc 0x1f3d27000 + 57596
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f3d35188 0x1f3d27000 + 57736
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001f45aa498 0x1f4549000 + 398488
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001f454de10 0x1f4549000 + 19984
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001f75e7a9c 0x1f759c000 + 309916
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001f75e7728 0x1f759c000 + 309032
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001f75e7d44 0x1f759c000 + 310596
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001f4b020e0 0x1f4a55000 + 708832
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001f4b02060 0x1f4a55000 + 708704
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001f4b01944 0x1f4a55000 + 706884
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001f4afc810 0x1f4a55000 + 686096
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001f4afc0e0 0x1f4a55000 + 684256
18  GraphicsServices                0x00000001f6d75584 0x1f6d6a000 + 46468
19  UIKitCore                       0x0000000221a50c00 0x221168000 + 9341952
20  appName                             0x0000000100fd62d0 0x100fd0000 + 25296
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001f45babb4 0x1f45ba000 + 2996

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f478fce8 0x1f4781000 + 60648

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f478fce8 0x1f4781000 + 60648

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f478fce8 0x1f4781000 + 60648

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001f46fbea4 0x1f46e4000 + 97956
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001f46fb37c 0x1f46e4000 + 95100
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001f4b01ad8 0x1f4a55000 + 707288
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001f4afc974 0x1f4a55000 + 686452
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001f4afc0e0 0x1f4a55000 + 684256
5   Foundation                      0x00000001f54f2494 0x1f54ea000 + 33940
6   Foundation                      0x00000001f54f2340 0x1f54ea000 + 33600
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000221b410c4 0x221168000 + 10326212
8   Foundation                      0x00000001f562523c 0x1f54ea000 + 1290812
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f478c25c 0x1f4781000 + 45660
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f478c1bc 0x1f4781000 + 45500
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f478fcf4 0x1f4781000 + 60660

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f478fce8 0x1f4781000 + 60648

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f478fce8 0x1f4781000 + 60648

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f478fce8 0x1f4781000 + 60648

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):    
0x207918000 - 0x207975fff ImageCapture arm64  <45f217d34db239b188a248daada67d2b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageCapture.framework/ImageCapture
0x208597000 - 0x20859dfff LinguisticData arm64  <33e9c5f1892f302983980fb3b711998a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LinguisticData.framework/LinguisticData
0x208c49000 - 0x208c81fff StoreKit arm64  <facdf389202830ef9cf0d98d780f6b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x209c47000 - 0x209d0efff PDFKit arm64  <03d0dacc8a033e10b8b6fe9c457046cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/PDFKit.framework/PDFKit
0x20a0b9000 - 0x20a0cbfff MobileDeviceLink arm64  <74de7d2ef66b3e0287231da7a93732b3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x20a1b8000 - 0x20a201fff MobileBackup arm64  <c12adcf05b1f370cacb7f8efccf7b622> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBackup.framework/MobileBackup
0x20a202000 - 0x20a24ffff SafariSafeBrowsing arm64  <b3dc3399eedc36c09f5ffc2882f55081> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SafariSafeBrowsing.framework/SafariSafeBrowsing
0x20a762000 - 0x20a860fff MessageUI arm64  <e1917f87762c3717b1539851d8c1bace> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x20be52000 - 0x20beabfff CallKit arm64  <5e885043d938371ea86f9fa966ad86d6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CallKit.framework/CallKit
0x20cc17000 - 0x20cc6afff LoggingSupport arm64  <1f1c6027db803b0da5d603c7892d70eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoggingSupport.framework/LoggingSupport
0x20ed20000 - 0x20ed44fff AppSupportUI arm64  <e37d8a902823367a9a73d4da95d2d84b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupportUI.framework/AppSupportUI
0x20faff000 - 0x20fb04fff kperf arm64  <aacc436be4413558911784d3c5868717> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/kperf.framework/kperf
0x20fd5e000 - 0x20fd84fff CellularPlanManager arm64  <a61afefa2dd5343aa7fd7848f0b9fef6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CellularPlanManager.framework/CellularPlanManager
0x20ff6c000 - 0x20ff74fff kperfdata arm64  <07cdf27744d53c899ef6568ca60a93d7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/kperfdata.framework/kperfdata
0x20ffba000 - 0x20ffc2fff libdscsym.dylib arm64  <fc8036818e1c37a6897f171a625e6b30> /usr/lib/libdscsym.dylib
0x210390000 - 0x2103cbfff ktrace arm64  <5e716bd202b433d599fd14e8ae790d5b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ktrace.framework/ktrace
0x212686000 - 0x212695fff CTCarrierSpace arm64  <5bd71f5764953d509aa3d71588943f8c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CTCarrierSpace.framework/CTCarrierSpace
0x212b2d000 - 0x212b41fff DeviceIdentity arm64  <524b6854c2db316789910b6879620eea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DeviceIdentity.framework/DeviceIdentity
0x214c5c000 - 0x214c98fff Rapport arm64  <6503af18058d3222a1a287fbab594cfa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Rapport.framework/Rapport
0x214cd5000 - 0x214cf2fff SignpostSupport arm64  <5c82dad2278137fab253183ff0198ad2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SignpostSupport.framework/SignpostSupport
0x215c47000 - 0x215c4efff libMatch.1.dylib arm64  <ac6125bf827f3d2aa0016866f220f1de> /usr/lib/libMatch.1.dylib
0x215c97000 - 0x215cb3fff libtailspin.dylib arm64  <ea7a0bb37fc8337e960fa41137219811> /usr/lib/libtailspin.dylib
0x2175d7000 - 0x2175dbfff PushKit arm64  <104065715a703dc695787cc0653cf5af> /System/Library/Frameworks/PushKit.framework/PushKit
0x219484000 - 0x21948bfff EmailCore arm64  <85567eaa748336db84bdf4030307c427> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EmailCore.framework/EmailCore
0x219499000 - 0x2194aafff libGSFontCache.dylib arm64  <af323cbcb5cc3c409e51377af12eb88c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
0x2194ab000 - 0x2194ddfff libTrueTypeScaler.dylib arm64  <015e8c878acc3f019b9c7a83f6606823> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libTrueTypeScaler.dylib
0x21aff5000 - 0x21aff9fff InternationalSupport arm64  <a9f9bcf0b66a318b8f4fe2ef30e1de4e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/InternationalSupport.framework/InternationalSupport
0x21c20a000 - 0x21c216fff PersonaUI arm64  <46a2953340543dcd8f740b39e81eca56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersonaUI.framework/PersonaUI
0x21c593000 - 0x21c59dfff SignpostCollection arm64  <adb35347388836f2be93bc78bbd25b15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SignpostCollection.framework/SignpostCollection
0x21d122000 - 0x21d125fff XCTTargetBootstrap arm64  <125834652e7a3a11bc651eaa9e666daf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCTTargetBootstrap.framework/XCTTargetBootstrap
0x21d168000 - 0x21d17afff libEDR arm64  <eb83850e8b51332eb927337cd510794d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/libEDR.framework/libEDR
0x21dcb9000 - 0x21dcb9fff libcharset.1.dylib arm64  <261ef847003736228dff4aa79221b198> /usr/lib/libcharset.1.dylib
0x21e788000 - 0x21e789fff libsandbox.1.dylib arm64  <96115773ec793ebc8a7744b0d3b0d960> /usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib
0x21e949000 - 0x21ea9dfff CoreServices arm64  <7ca0c8226edd3f0e9de6c9ada3f8854c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices
0x21eaca000 - 0x21eae3fff MPSRayIntersector arm64  <a59116136430388d88d2fc7069710099> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Frameworks/MPSRayIntersector.framework/MPSRayIntersector
0x21eb13000 - 0x21ec4efff Network arm64  <cf486b8fe27230998f9db137573d0919> /System/Library/Frameworks/Network.framework/Network
0x21ec59000 - 0x21ec67fff ANEServices arm64  <2cb537a340fc305e9b367d6829ce597b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ANEServices.framework/ANEServices
0x21ec6c000 - 0x21ec70fff ASEProcessing arm64  <3703b68e414f32dbbdd1ac4a97a7ba1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ASEProcessing.framework/ASEProcessing
0x21ec71000 - 0x21ec7cfff AXCoreUtilities arm64  <35b935e1fb03325a967b71c339a63fd1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AXCoreUtilities.framework/AXCoreUtilities
0x21eef7000 - 0x21f034fff AppleMediaServices arm64  <e900e6a7d5c8312da04eaebb917427b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleMediaServices.framework/AppleMediaServices
0x21f035000 - 0x21f044fff AppleNeuralEngine arm64  <ce5d2aaaf72e305a9221062401ccaec9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleNeuralEngine.framework/AppleNeuralEngine
0x21f1ce000 - 0x21f205fff C2 arm64  <04e0090ef3493354a65e6f4a3919ad37> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/C2.framework/C2
0x21f5ef000 - 0x21f60afff DoNotDisturb arm64  <55263d99b6823350943b771281915e94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DoNotDisturb.framework/DoNotDisturb
0x21f742000 - 0x21f79afff DocumentManager arm64  <efe8ee676487367180d6691106bbdbdc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DocumentManager.framework/DocumentManager
0x21f8d7000 - 0x21f8dbfff IdleTimerServices arm64  <c5d940c64ac53ef0a529cf996b367829> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IdleTimerServices.framework/IdleTimerServices
0x21f957000 - 0x21f982fff MetadataUtilities arm64  <b956b88e7e56373080ebba7760868b33> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetadataUtilities.framework/MetadataUtilities
0x21ff01000 - 0x21ff52fff OTSVG arm64  <120d3e9410e33b1fbfebc7db541098d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OTSVG.framework/OTSVG
0x220050000 - 0x2200affff PhotoFoundation arm64  <0908388d88763d02ab84a5489ddfa37d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoFoundation.framework/PhotoFoundation
0x220103000 - 0x220148fff PhotosImagingFoundation arm64  <74618eb684c13ca793e60c9596a273a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotosImagingFoundation.framework/PhotosImagingFoundation
0x22019c000 - 0x2201fcfff ROCKit arm64  <ab04ec8bccfe3770b46413ff6a9bab0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ROCKit.framework/ROCKit
0x22044d000 - 0x2204e7fff SampleAnalysis arm64  <fb22ef1fe16d3175ad56bf23e1e94a7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SampleAnalysis.framework/SampleAnalysis
0x2205cc000 - 0x2205ccfff SignpostNotification arm64  <7d1b1e317bea32ecaf71290b96d6e123> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SignpostNotification.framework/SignpostNotification
0x22063b000 - 0x220643fff StatsKit arm64  <64e328675e8b33fab748332751a870dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StatsKit.framework/StatsKit
0x221168000 - 0x22229dfff UIKitCore arm64  <db4b7f70039932b49da37218b5a4ba49> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x22229e000 - 0x2222a9fff UIKitServices arm64  <dc4399111db53da69d735b616bd65b90> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitServices.framework/UIKitServices
0x2222aa000 - 0x2222b1fff URLFormatting arm64  <6103f7f4467a38ac889cf6fc4946ef10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/URLFormatting.framework/URLFormatting

EOF
```

Comment: Even I m facing the same issue when trying to upload the app to appstore.Crash log is exact copy of above.

Comment: Did u resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have unsymbolicated crash,You can try symbolicating in 2 ways

1. [Symbolicating Crash Reports With atos.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATE_WITH_ATOS) you can follow the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBA7H_uYf34)
2. [Downloading the dSYM files from Xcode.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-DOWNLOAD_DSYM)

I was able to solve the problem with the help of video tutorial